# Find largest adjacent product in array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, spread-syntax

I'm trying to understand the following solution for finding the largest adjacent product in any given array.

Example:

```
 For inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], the output should be
 adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) = 21.

 7 and 3 produce the largest product.
```

Possible solution in JS:

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(arr) {
  return Math.max(...arr.slice(1).map((x,i)=>[x*arr[i]]))
  }
```

I am having a hard time understanding two things:

1. What do the three dots exactly do and how does this get passed into the function? Is there any way to write this in a more understandable way? I know that is the "spread syntax" feature in ES6, but still don't understand completely.
2. Why do we insert "1" as argument to slice? My first though was to input "0", because we want to start at the start, then loop through everything, and see which adjacent product is the largest.

I'd appreciate any advice, links and explanations.

Thanks.

Cheers!

Comment: 1 - read spread docs, or transpile to ES5 to see what it does [transpiled here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCYCtkQKZigUQBtsBbXKAZwAUAnOVEaACmRpoEpEBvAKEURrYoIGkgCyyKAAsAdCWQAPJjJWsaMioRg4mARnZzkAByZMFAGhjsAvAD4A2goBUa-zAC679ux4BfIA), 2 - because with *n* items in an array, you want to check *n - 1* products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What do the three dots exactly do and how does this get passed into the function? Is there any way to write this in a more understandable way? I know that is some kind of "spread" feature in ES6, but still don't understand completely.**

The `Math#max` needs a list of numbers as parameters, and map produces an array. The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is used to convert an array to be expanded to a list of parameters.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log('max on array', Math.max(arr));

console.log('max on list of parameters', Math.max(...arr));
```

In this case you can use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to convert the array to a list of parameters. I find it less readable, however.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, arr));
```

**2. Why do we insert "1" as argument to slice? My first though was to input "0", because we want to start at the start, then loop through everything, and see which adjacent product is the largest.**

Lets break down the iteration order of the 2 arrays.

```
[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3] // inputArray
[6, -2, -5, 7, 3] // inputArray.slice(1)
```

Now on each iteration of `inputArray.slice(1)`:

```
x: 6, i = 0, arr[0] = 3
x: -2, i = 1, arr[1] = 6
x: -5, i = 2, arr[2] = -2
```

Since the `inputArray.slice(1)` array starts from the 2nd element of the `inputArray`, the index (`i`) points to the 1st element of the `inputArray`. And the result is an array of products of 2 adjacent numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Welcome :) Don't forget to follow the links, to get more information about how spread and apply work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var biggestProduct =  inputArray[0] *  inputArray[1];

for (i=0;  i<inputArray.length-1 ; ++i) 
{
  console.log(biggestProduct)
  if   ((inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] ) > biggestProduct) 
  { 
    biggestProduct = inputArray[i]  *  inputArray[i+1] 
  }
}
return biggestProduct;
```

Note: I've declared a variable that consists of 2 input arrays with index number then starts a for loop that indicates input array with his index number, so by that he will go throw all the index number of the array (one of them raised by one so that they won't be at the same value). and at the end of the code, you have the if statement.

Comment: I've declared a variable that consists tow input arrays with index number
then starts a for loop that indicates input array with his index number, so by that he will go throw all the index number of the array (one of them raised by one so that they won't be at the same value).
and at the end of the code, you have the if statement.
hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do as follows;

```js
function getNeigboringMaxProduct([x,...xs], r = -Infinity){
  var p = x * xs[0];
  return xs.length ? getNeigboringMaxProduct(xs, p > r ? p : r)
                   : r;
}

var arr = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3],
    res = getNeigboringMaxProduct(arr);
console.log(res);
```